# Powershell GCI cannot find path but later says path already exists

Tags: powershell

I have a script that for every user, deletes a folder if it exists, renames a folder, creates a new folder, then copies a folder from another user.
I have verified the folder exists using File Explorer and using "Test-Path" but my script says it doesn't exist then later says it can't create the new folder because it already exists.

I get the errors:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes.old'

Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 
'C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes' does not exist.

md : An item with the specified name C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes 
already exists.
```

My script:

```
$Source = 'C:\Users\ADMINUSER\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes'
$users = Get-ChildItem c:\users|where{$_.name -notmatch 'Public|default|ADMINUSER'}
foreach ($user in $users){
    $FolderName = "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes.old"
    if (Test-Path $FolderName) {
        Gci $FolderName | Foreach{Remove-Item -Path $FolderName -Force -Recurse}
    }
    if (Test-Path "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes") {
        Gci "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client" | Foreach{Rename-Item -Path "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes" -NewName "Nodes.old"}
    }
    if (Test-Path "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes") {
        Write-Host
    }
    else {
        Gci "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client" | Foreach{md "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes"}
    }
    if (Test-Path "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client\Nodes") {
        Gci "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client" | Foreach{Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Avigilon\Client" -Force -Recurse}
    }
}
```

I run this script to update the Site Lists in the Avigilon app because their built-in "Share Sites" doesn't always work properly.

Comment: What exactly is `Gci $FolderName | Foreach{Remove-Item -Path $FolderName -Force -Recurse}` meant to accomplish? Are you trying to remove the whole folder, or only its contents?

Comment: It is meant to remove the old folder if it exists.
The first time it runs, "Nodes.old" will not be there. But the next time I run it, the whole "Nodes.old" folder should be removed.

Comment: But you've already tested that exists with `Test-Path` in the condition, so all you need is `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $FolderName -Force -Recurse` inside the `if` block, no need for `gci` at all